# Investment capital calculator(Python)

Tags: python, classes

The program is simulate a situation where my goal is to lose money in `Corresponding exchange`, however I will win `max_lose` times with `min_amount_per_lot` amount in `Corresponding exchange` and lose the same amount in `Bybit`, using [martingale strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)) in `Bybit` will lead to magnify the capital needed in `Bybit` each time losing in `Corresponding exchange`.

An example of `max_lose` = 3:

```
# Let am = min_amount_per_lot
# 0. CorrespondingExchange: am, Bybit: am
# After winning 100% in CorrespondingExchange:
# 1. CorrespondingExchange: am + am, Bybit: 0
# After winning 100% in CorrespondingExchange again:
# 2. CorrespondingExchange: am + am + am*2, Bybit: -am*2
# After winning 100% in CorrespondingExchange again:
# 3. CorrespondingExchange: am + amv + am*2 + am*4, Bybit: -am*6
# min capital needed in Bybit: am--am*6
# total amount needed: am+am--am*6
```

```
from pybit import usdt_perpetual


class CorrespondingExchange:
    leverage: int = 50
    transaction_cost: int = 1

    def __init__(self, lot_size):
        self.lot_size = lot_size

    def generate_transaction_cost(self) -> int:
        """
        calculate the transaction needed per trade in corresponding exchange,
        :return: transaction cost
        """
        return self.transaction_cost * self.lot_size

    def show_result(self) -> None:
        """
        Print the infomation needed which is related corresponding exchange.
        :return:
        """
        print(f"transaction cost for corresponding exchange is: {self.generate_transaction_cost()}")


class Bybit:

    session_unauth = usdt_perpetual.HTTP(endpoint="https://api.bybit.com")
    taker_fee: float = 0.06

    def __init__(self, lot_size: int, max_lose: int, buffer: float, symbol: str):
        self.max_lose = max_lose
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.lot_size = lot_size

    def calculate_min_capital(self) -> float:
        """
        Caluclate the minimum capital needed in Bybit base on the parameter's setting
        :return: minimum capital
        """
        min_amount = self.generate_min_amount_per_lot()
        return (2 ** self.max_lose - 1) * min_amount * (1 + self.buffer)

    def generate_min_amount_per_lot(self) -> float:
        """
        Calculate the minimum amount needed in order to trade one lot in corresponding exchange
        :return: USDT amount per lot
        """
        return self.get_latest_bid() * self.lot_size / CorrespondingExchange.leverage

    def get_latest_bid(self) -> float:
        """
        Get the latest symbol's bid price from Bybit
        :return: latest bid price
        """
        result = self.session_unauth.orderbook(symbol=self.symbol)["result"]
        return float(result[0]["price"])

    def calculate_transaction_cost(self) -> float:
        """
        Calculate the transaction needed in Bybit per trade
        :return: transaction cost
        """
        return self.get_latest_bid() * self.lot_size * self.taker_fee / 100 * 2

    def show_result(self) -> None:
        """
        Print the calulator result.
        :return:
        """
        min_amount_per_lot = self.generate_min_amount_per_lot()
        min_cap = self.calculate_min_capital()
        total_cap = min_amount_per_lot + min_cap
        print(f"min amount per trade in corresponding exchange: {min_amount_per_lot:.1f}")
        print(f"min capital needed in Bybit: {min_cap:.1f}")
        print(f"total amount needed: {total_cap:.1f}")
        print(f"transaction cost for Bybit is: {self.calculate_transaction_cost():.1f}")


class MartingaleCalculator:
    def __init__(self, lot_size: int, max_lose: int, buffer: float, symbol: str = "BTCUSDT"):
        self.max_lose = max_lose
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.lot_size = lot_size
        self.symbol = symbol

    def run(self) -> None:
        """
        Gathering two exchange to show the result.
        :return:
        """
        bybit = Bybit(lot_size=self.lot_size, max_lose=self.max_lose, buffer=self.buffer, symbol=self.symbol)
        corr_exchange = CorrespondingExchange(lot_size=self.lot_size)

        bybit.show_result()
        corr_exchange.show_result()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calculator = MartingaleCalculator(lot_size=1, max_lose=5, buffer=0.1, symbol="ETHUSDT")
    calculator.run()
```

Print output:

```
# min amount per trade in corresponding exchange: 31.1
# min capital needed in Bybit: 1060.4
# total amount needed: 1091.5
# transaction cost for Bybit is: 1.9
# transaction cost for corresponding exchange is: 1
```

Is there anything that can be improved in terms of program structures(e.g. cohesion, OOP)  docstring(especially under the class), type-hint, efficiency, and readability?

Suppose `generate_min_amount_per_lot` should be inside `CorrespondingExchange` since it is dependent on the `leverage` of `CorrespondingExchange`. Is there any way how to move it into `CorrespondingExchange`?

And what if I want to make it more user-friendly, besides using `input()` to replace parameters of `MartingaleCalculator()`? Is there any package or script I can add to make it handy to use?

Comment: I didn't manage to wrap my brain around the first paragraph, can you explain it in simple words?

Comment: Added an example,  please let me know if the words still make you confused, sorry for inconvenience. @QuasiStellar